# Android opening a dialogfragment from another fragment throws a casting error

Tags: java, android

I have really browsed through stackoverflow for this solution.
Im trying to access a fragment from another fragment and an error is thrown that

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.noel.myapplication99.IncomeTax cannot be cast to com.noel.myapplication99.IncomeDialog
        at com.noel.myapplication99.MainActivity.createOutput(MainActivity.java:119)
        at com.noel.myapplication99.IncomeTax$1.onClick(IncomeTax.java:77)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4785)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19869)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5696)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1028)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823)
```

These are my codes
**MainActivity.java**

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements IncomeTax.OnFragmentInteractionListener, ResidentialIncomeTax.OnFragmentInteractionListener, NavigationDrawerFragment.NavigationDrawerCallbacks, IncomeTax.IncomeTaxListener {


    public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri){
    }
    private NavigationDrawerFragment mNavigationDrawerFragment;

    private CharSequence mTitle;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
                getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
        mTitle = getTitle();

        // Set up the drawer.
        mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(
                R.id.navigation_drawer,
                (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));

    }

    @Override
    public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        Fragment fragment=null;
        switch(position)
        {
            case 0:
                fragment = new IncomeTax();
                mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section1);
                break;
            case 1:
                fragment = new ResidentialIncomeTax();
                mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section2);
                break;
        }

        if(fragment!=null)

        {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fragment, "Tag").commit();
        }
    }



    public void onSectionAttached(int number) {
        switch (number) {

        }
    }

    public void restoreActionBar() {
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setTitle(mTitle);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        if (!mNavigationDrawerFragment.isDrawerOpen()) {
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            restoreActionBar();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void createOutput(int i, int f) {
        IncomeDialog incomeDialog = (IncomeDialog) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("Tag");
        incomeDialog.setOutputText(i, f);
    }

    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";
        public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
            PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
            super.onAttach(activity);
            ((MainActivity) activity).onSectionAttached(
                    getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER));
        }
    }

}
```

**IncomeTax.java**

```
public class IncomeTax extends Fragment implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

IncomeTaxListener  activityCommander;
float selectedIncomeType;

public interface IncomeTaxListener{
    public void createOutput(int i, int f);
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    try{
        activityCommander = (IncomeTaxListener) context;
    }catch(Exception e){
        throw new ClassCastException(toString());
    }
}

private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;
public IncomeTax() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {

    }
}

Button btnIcCalc;
EditText salary, insuaranceRelief;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_income_tax, container, false);
    salary = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.tvSalary);
    insuaranceRelief = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.tvReliefCalc);
    btnIcCalc = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btnIcCalc);


    final int iSalary=0;
    final int iInsuranceRelief=1;

    btnIcCalc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Dialog box here
            activityCommander.createOutput(iSalary, iInsuranceRelief);
            FragmentManager manager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
            IncomeDialog myDialog = new IncomeDialog();
            myDialog.setTargetFragment(IncomeTax.this, 0);
            myDialog.show(manager, "IncomeDialog");
        }
    });


    setSpinnerContent(view);
    return view;
}


private void setSpinnerContent( View view )
{

   Spinner spinner = (Spinner) view.findViewById( R.id.incomeTypeSpinner );
    ArrayAdapter incomeSpinnerArrayAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this.getActivity(), R.array.income_type_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

    spinner.setAdapter(incomeSpinnerArrayAdapter );
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
}



@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    try {
        mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
    }
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mListener = null;
}

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    switch (position){
        case 0:
            selectedIncomeType = 1;

        break;
        case 1:
            selectedIncomeType = 1;
        break;
    }

}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

}
```

**IncomeDialog.java**

```
public class IncomeDialog extends DialogFragment {

public IncomeDialog() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

TextView netPay, insuranceRelief;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_income_dialog, null);
    netPay = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvNetPay);
    insuranceRelief = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvPersonalRelief);
    return view;

}
public void setOutputText(int i, int f){
    netPay.setText(i);
    insuranceRelief.setText(f);

}
```

Comment: Because you are trying to cast `IncomeTax` to `IncomeDialog`

Comment: BTW, what are you trying to achieve here? `@Override
    public void createOutput(int i, int f) {
        IncomeDialog incomeDialog = (IncomeDialog) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("Tag");
        incomeDialog.setOutputText(i, f);
    }`

Comment: I'm trying to send the output to IncomeDialog fragment

Comment: Sorr if Im not clear but im just a noob

Comment: You want to send data to Dialog while creating it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to send data to `DialogFragmet` then try like this:

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putInt("key1", i);
bundle.putInt("key2", f);
IncomeDialog incomeDialog = new IncomeDialog();
incomeDialog.setArguments(bundle);
```

Now carry out `FragmentTransaction` to add this `incomeDialog`. That will show the dialog.

To receive the bundle data in `IncomeDialog`:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_income_dialog, null);
    netPay = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvNetPay);
    insuranceRelief = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvPersonalRelief);

    Bundle bundle=getArguments();
    int i = bundle.getInt("key1");
    int f = bundle.getInt("key2");

    return view;
}
```

Comment: Thanks it worked.... but when Im trying to send data of type string it doesn't work with putInt

Comment: Use `putString` because you are sending `String` not `int`